# Pressing UI buttons alongside processing Input.GetMouseDown() in Update

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

The game I'm making is meant for mobile devices.

I have a `PlayerInput` class in which I check for mouse events in `Update()`:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        //hide UI elements
    }
}
```

I have a button which I hide when I detect mouse input in `PlayerInput` class but I don't want to hide it if the player presses the button.
I've managed to solve this issue by adding this component to my UI elements:

```
public class UiPointerHandler : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        //disable mouse checks
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        //enable mouse checks
    }
}
```

It allows me to disable processing mouse events in `PlayerInput`'s `Update()` to interact with certain UI elements.

This does its job fairly well on PC when I'm testing/prototyping the game but when I build the game for mobile it doesn't work at all and I can't press the buttons.

I'm looking for a solution that would work on mobile as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this fairly easily by adding the following check

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && !EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
    {
        //hide UI elements
    } 
}
```

What this does is it checks if your pointer (mouse or finger) is over an UI element. By checking if it's not, you get your desired behaviour.

Comment: This helped but did not solve the problem on its own.

Comment: @DonAndre that is basically because you didn't tell us what `// disable mouse checks` and `// enable mouse checks` means ...

Answer (score 0):

See "Input.GetTouch" on 'Input' class on Unity, GetMouseButtonDown doesn't work on mobile. Unity designed 'Touch' event on mobile instead of mouse event so try it. it has to work with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user Immorality I've managed to solve my problem.

I've added the `EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()` check to the `Update()` inside of my `PlayerInput` class.

```
void Update()
{
    if(EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()) return;

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        //hide UI elements
    }
}
```

I've tested this solution on its own and it did not help in my case, I still wasn't able to press the buttons.

I've introduced a bool in `PlayerInput` which controls whether the mouse input is being processed and 2 static methods allowing to change this variable.

```
public class PlayerInput : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static bool _transmitInput;

    void Update()
    {
        if(!_transmitInput || EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()) return;

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
        //hide UI elements
        }
    }

    public static void DisableInput()
    {
        if (!_transmitInput) return;

        _transmitInput = false;
    }

    public static void EnableInput()
    {
        if (_transmitInput) return;

        _transmitInput = true;
    }
}
```

These are called from the `UiPointerHandler`:

```
public class UiPointerHandler : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        PlayerInput.DisableInput();
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        PlayerInput.EnableInput();
    }
}
```

At this point I was still having problems on mobile. When pressing the button, the `OnPointerEnter()` would be called but `OnPointerExit()` would not.

I assume it is because of how my scene is set up. The 2 buttons I'm working with are in the same position and are the same size. I just disable one and enable the other.

I solved this issue by calling `PlayerInput.EnableInput()` in the `onClick` of the buttons.

Comment: Note that your `if (!_transmitInput) return;` is completely redundant! It is faster to simply set the `_transmitInput` value than to check it first.